# Compare Opportunity with other opportunities on same account

Tags: cpq

On CPQ Contract obj I have Renewal opportunity. Before performing renewal I need to check other opportunities on same account.
If any opportunity found in closed won stage and same contract start date as renewal opportunity then I need to send email to ED else I need to update renewal opportunity.
But in loop I need to ensure I am comparing opportunities with same account.

```
For(Contract con : scope)
{
    
    OppidSet.add(con.SBQQ__RenewalOpportunity__c);
   
} 

    //Query Opp here and it in list List<opp> Renopp
    List<opportunity> RenOpp =[select id,SBQQ__PrimaryQuote__c from opportunity where id in:OppidSet];

   For(Opportunity op: RenOpp)
   {
       setofAccountIds.add(op.accountid);
   }
    
        opplinktoAccount = [select id, AccountId, account.Name, Contract_Expiration_Date__c, Contract_Start_Date__c from Opportunity 
                            where StageName='Closed Won' AND AccountId  IN :setofAccountIds and 
                            id NOT IN :OppidSet];
        if(lstOpptyslinkedToAccount.size() > 0)

    
     For(Opportunity opty : Renopp)

    {
        For(opportunity opty1:opplinktoAccount)
        {
            
                if(opty.AccountId == opty1.Accountid && opty.Contract_Expiration_Date__c == opty1.Contract_Expiration_Date__c && opty.Contract_Start_Date__c==opty1.Contract_Start_Date__c)
                {
                    //Send Email
                }
            
            Else{
                //Renewal opp to update
                FinalOppset.add(opty.id);
                }
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You are going to want to use a map of accountId -> list of opportunity. Note that your first SELECT statement needs to include AccountId